# MySQL repeated COUNT in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

Will it make any difference in terms of performance if i will break the query below into two, one for the `COUNT()` and the other `SUM's`?

```
SELECT 
  SUM(c1)*100/COUNT(id), 
  SUM(c2)*100/COUNT(id), 
  SUM(c3)*100/COUNT(id)...
```

Comment: I believe, mysql can cache it.

Comment: Whether it caches it or not is not terribly relevant. -- Fetching the rows dominates the query execution time, not simple function(s).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `id` is never `NULL`, you can just use `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(c1) * 100, 
       AVG(c2) * 100, 
       AVG(c3) * 100...
```

However, I don't know what you really mean by your question.

Comment: I'm wodering if MySQL do the COUNTing three times based on the given query. If so, would it be better if separate the COUNT and use the result on the second query getting rid of the COUNT divisors.

Answer (score 2):

No, keep it as a single query. MySQL will do the aggregations once.
You could have done a test however by running both queries and determining yourself which is the quickest method.

Comment: I can't find from the documentation that support "MySQL will do the aggregations once."